# How to create region indicator variables from a state list in R

Tags: r, list, vector

I have a variable that lists which states each company are active in. I am hoping to be able to create some kind of region (west, south, midwest etc.) variable. In this case, it is possible for each company to be in more than one region.

My approach so far has been to define region vectors, and then try to define indicator variables (dat$westYN, dat$southYN, etc) with 1 if that company operates in a state in that region and 0 otherwise.

I have used str_split to break apart the state character strings, but I am struggling with how to work with the resulting list.

In this case, it is working when dat$state is a single value, but not when there are multiple states.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
id <- 1:20
state <- c("NJ, NY", 
       "ID, OR", 
       "CA", 
       "FL, MO, NC, RI", 
       "TX DE, KY, MD, MA, NH, NJ, PA, RI, WV",
       "FL, KY, TN", 
       "DC, MD, VA", 
       "NY",
       "AZ, NM",
       "FL, NJ, NY",
       "IN, MI",
       "GA, SC", 
       "NV", 
       "AR, CO, KY, MO, TN, TX",
       "OH", 
       "NC", 
       "FL", 
       "IL", 
       "AZ", 
       "CA, CT, IL, MA, OH, PA, UT, WV"
       )

dat <- data.frame(id, state)

west <- c("WA", "OR", "CA", "NV", "AZ", "ID", "MT", "WY",
      "CO", "NM", "UT")
south <- c("TX", "OK", "AR", "LA", "MS", "AL", "TN", "KY",
       "GA", "FL", "SC", "NC", "VA", "WV")
midwest <- c("KS", "NE", "SD", "ND", "MN", "MO", "IA", "IL",
         "IN", "MI", "WI", "OH")
northeast <- c("ME", "NH", "NY", "MA", "RI", "VT", "PA", 
           "NJ", "CT", "DE", "MD", "DC")

stateList <- stringr::str_split(dat$state, ",")

dat$westYN <- ifelse(is.element(stateList, west), 1, 0)
dat$southYN <- ifelse(is.element(stateList, south), 1, 0)
dat$midwestYN <- ifelse(is.element(stateList, midwest), 1, 0)
dat$northeastYN <- ifelse(is.element(stateList, northeast), 1, 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

First, I think you are better off storing related information in a list rather than separate variables

```
regions <- list(
  west = c("WA", "OR", "CA", "NV", "AZ", "ID", "MT", "WY",
          "CO", "NM", "UT"),
  south = c("TX", "OK", "AR", "LA", "MS", "AL", "TN", "KY",
           "GA", "FL", "SC", "NC", "VA", "WV"),
  midwest = c("KS", "NE", "SD", "ND", "MN", "MO", "IA", "IL",
             "IN", "MI", "WI", "OH"),
  northeast = c("ME", "NH", "NY", "MA", "RI", "VT", "PA", 
              "NJ", "CT", "DE", "MD", "DC")
)
```

Then you can more easily do a loop to create your variables

```
for(region in names(regions)) {
  dat[[paste0(region, "YN")]] <-sapply(stateList, function(x) any(trimws(x) %in% regions[[region]]))
}
```

Or using the regular vairables

```
dat$westYN <- sapply(stateList, function(x) any(x %in% west))
dat$southYN <- sapply(stateList, function(x) any(x %in% south))
dat$midwestYN <- sapply(stateList, function(x) any(x %in% midwest))
dat$northeastYN <- sapply(stateList, function(x) any(x %in% northeast))
```

The trick is to use `any()` to see if any of the values match one of the states in each region.

Comment: Thank you so your recommendations! In running your code, I noticed that the rows which have states from multiple regions are not producing the correct result. For example id 20 only has west being true, when it should be true for all regions. Furthermore id 5 is false across the board? Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: @EmmaKortemeier @MrFlick You still need to trim the white space.  This can be done by using `any(trimws(x)` in place of `any(x` in the answer.  I have submitted a revision to the answer, but it is pending peer review still.

Comment: @jmuhlenkamp That seems to have solved it! Thank you!!